# PeformUpkeep does not execute when checkUpkeep returns true using Chainlink automation

Tags: solidity, chainlink, chainlink-keepers

We are using a custom logic automation.  when checking checkUpkeep the boolean returns true (pic attached) but our perform upkeep doesn't run.  It is calling another function to run that cost rougly 50k to 100k in gas (when run manually)  What are we missing?   (p.s. when we do a simple toggle function call the performUpkeep works - but not our function).  I've even put the gas up to 2,500,000 for testing using a timebased option as well (calling a specific function to execute same logic).  Here is the repo https://github.com/billyjitsu/expir3/tree/main/packages/backend/contracts

WE are expecting when the checkUpkeep returns true to execute the upkeep

Comment: Your github link is broken and can you edit your answer to post your smart contract?

Comment: Sorry. Gut now public

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the problem like "Why Chainlink checkUpkeep does not execute", I suggest doing the following things to debug your upkeep.

1. Since `checkUpkeep` and `performUpkeep` are both triggered by [Chainlink automation](https://automation.chain.link/), you need to check your automation subscription first. In the automation app, double check the contract address is correct.
2. Because the chainlink node has to change the state of blockchain(call `performUpkeep` in your consumer contract), it has to pay the gas fee. It is important to make sure there is a minimum balance of LINK in your subscription.
3. Test if `checkUpkeep` works as expected. If the pre-defined condition for automation is satisfied in your smart contract, `checkUpkeep` should return true. Chainlink automation only calls `performUpkeep` when `checkUpkeep` returns `true`, so the upkeep does not work if `checkUpkeep` cannot return true. Call `checkUpkeep` by yourself to test if it works properly. If you cannot get `true` as returned value, automation cannot get `true` either.
4. Test if `performUpkeep` works as expected. The mechanism of Chainlink automation is to call `performUpkeep` when `checkUpkeep` returns `true`, so you must make sure the `performUpkeep` can be called by automation. Try to call the `performUpkeep` manually to see if it works properly.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, I have verified that checkupkeep returns true under my conditions.  I even created a fake toggle function to test it and it works.   The issue is the function i want to happen doesn't work.  I've raised the gas to 2.5m and given then automation about 35 link to test.  Manually running performUpkeep costs about 100k gas.  So at a loss as to why it doesn't run.   I also tried a timed contract and chose a manual function that mimics the same thing and no luck. Still between 75k to 100k gas

Comment: Hi @Billyjitsu, can you check if you have the correct contract address in your automation subscription and if they are on the same test net. I cannot debug for you since your codes in github give me errors when deploying through remix.